# MUI Modal doesn't fit in the screen

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Modal of MUI and I want to display a big json in the modal.

But the top of the modal doesn't fit in the screen and even after making it scrollable, I can't scroll to see the top.

Here is my react component:

```
const modal = (task_definition: string) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleOpen = () => { 
    setOpen(true);
  };
  const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);

  const style = {
    position: 'absolute' as 'absolute',
    top: '50%',
    left: '50%',
    transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
    width: '75%',
    bgcolor: '#333333',
    border: '2px solid #000',
    boxShadow: 24,
    p: 4
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={handleOpen}>Describe Task</Button>
      <Modal
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
        style={{ overflow: "auto" }}
      >
        <Box sx={{...style, overflow: "auto"}}>
          <Typography id="modal-modal-title" variant="h6" component="h2">
            Task Definition Described
          </Typography>
          <Typography id="modal-modal-description" sx={{ mt: 2 }} component={'span'}>
               {prettyJson(task_definition)}
          </Typography>
        </Box>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Which css property do I need to configure to my modal fits properly?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this, you need to adjust the positioning of the modal so that it fits within the screen height while also being scrollable.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Modal, Box, Typography } from '@mui/material';

const MyModal = ({ taskDefinition }) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const modalStyle = {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '50%', // Center vertically
    left: '50%', // Center horizontally
    transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
    width: '90%', // Adjust the width as needed
    height: '90vh', // Use viewport height to make sure it fits within the screen
    bgcolor: '#333333',
    border: '2px solid #000',
    boxShadow: 24,
    p: 4,
    overflowY: 'auto', // Enable vertical scrolling
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={handleOpen}>Describe Task</Button>
      <Modal
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
      >
        <Box sx={modalStyle}>
          <Typography variant="h6" component="h2" id="modal-modal-title">
            Task Definition Described
          </Typography>
          <Typography sx={{ mt: 2 }} component={'span'} id="modal-modal-description">
            {JSON.stringify(taskDefinition, null, 2)}
          </Typography>
        </Box>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyModal;
```